# Why is index never == 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
      <script>
        var index = 0;
        $.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(json) {
          $.each(json, function(data) {
            var html = "";                
            if(index == 0)
            {
              console.log(index + " first item");
              html = "<div class='item active'>";
            } else {
              console.log(index + " its not 0");
              html = "<div class='item'>"
            }
            console.log(json.length); // this will show the info it in firebug console
            html += "<blockquote><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3 text-center'><img class='img-circle' src='images/obama.jpg' style='width: 100px;height:100px;'></div><div class='col-sm-9'><p>Change will not come if we wait for some other person or some other time. We are the ones we've been waiting for. We are the change that we seek.</p><small>President Barack Obama</small></div></div></blockquote></div>";
            $('body').append(html);
            index++;
          });
        });
      </script>
```

I need to generate 5 of these but the first one needs to be have **'item active'**

### If there is a better way, please let me know

Thank you for pointing out that my html was being overwritten. I updated my code but jQuery isn't actually placing my HTML into the body. so thats another question

Comment: Given that code, I can't see any reason why the index wouldn't **always** be 0

Comment: You always overwrite `html`, rendering your if statement redundant.

Comment: you never change index, so it'll ALWAYS be zero...

Comment: What does your log say "index" is?

Comment: But it is NEVER entering my if index == 0 loop

Comment: @softwareisfun it's **always** running the `if` code, but your code still overwrites the value of `html` immediately after the `if` block anyway.

Comment: You never increment index from 0, should always fire the item active. not to mention the second "html =" should be contained within an else otherwise it will override the previous "html =".

Comment: @softwareisfun — What is it logging when you log the value of `index`? Is it even entering your `$.each` loop?

Comment: Maybe add a jsfiddle to see what's wrong...

Comment: Are you getting the data perfectly from json?

Comment: what is coming console.log(index) ? i suspect it is not zero. If I am right then change the name of variable to something as index would have been used by jquery ajax.

Comment: the index is working fine now. Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an index into the [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method; this will span from 0 to data.length - 1

```js
$.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(json) {
  $.each(json, function(index, data) {
    var html = "";
    html += '<div class="item' + (index == 0 ? ' active' : '') + '">';
    html += '<blockquote>...</blockquote>';
    html += '</div>';
    $('body').append(html);
  });
});
```

Comment: Was just about to hit publish on the same thing. +1, for OP: heres a link to the $.each api: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    var index = 0;
    $.getJSON("./data/data.json", function(json) {
      $.each(json, function(data) {
        var html = "";

        if(index == 0)
            html = "<div class='item active'>";
        else
            html = "<div class='item'>";

        html += "<blockquote><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-3 text-center'><img class='img-circle' src='images/obama.jpg' style='width: 100px;height:100px;'></div><div class='col-sm-9'><p>Change will not come if we wait for some other person or some other time. We are the ones we've been waiting for. We are the change that we seek.</p><small>President Barack Obama</small></div></div></blockquote></div>";

        $('body').append(html);
      index++;
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need for a separate counter - Have a look at @ChrisForrence answer

Comment: @Christer Completely overlooked the fact it's within a jquery each haha.